# JavaMail issues-no exception thrown and no mail received

Tags: java, email

I have a java program that runs from the command line. I tested this code on my development machine and the mail part works fine. 
When I deploy the code to my staging environment, the emails are not received - no exceptions are thrown. I tested the staging machine's connectivity to the mail server via telnet and sent myself an email from the staging machine via telnet and received it. Everything looks fine from a telnet manual mail session, but the mails from my java code are not received.
I also checked for anti-virus software on the staging machine and did not find any. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: A firewall probably or another agent. Check if you haven't received a failure email from the mail server.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, if there was a firewall or another software blocking the mail, would I be able to successfully send an email via telnet?